# Setting mode-line font size and Magit diff colours

Tags: magit, fonts, ediff

I'd like to adjust the background colour of the part of the diffs displayed by Magit. In particular, the background colour of the text `1st`, `2nd`, and `3rd` in the image. I'd like to increase the contrast between the background of the unchanged section and the changed section.

What is the correct setting to customize?

[image: Image of my emacs session]

Also, when I recently restarted emacs, it started showing the mode-line and section headers in a very small font (as shown).  How do I change these font sizes to be the same as the regular text?

Emacs version:
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) of 2017-09-12 on x86-017.build.eng.bos.redhat.com

Magit version: Some version from five years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs the appearance of certain text is controlled using something called "faces". You should learn about faces and how to change them by reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html).

To quickly change how something looks you can often put point (aka the cursor) on that thing that you want to change and then type `M-x customize-face`. That will often offer you the appropriate face as default completion candidate. Type `RET` to select it and then modify the face in the customization interface that shows up.

You cannot place the cursor in the mode-line to figure out the appropriate face as described above, but assuming that it is named `mode-line` would be a safe guess.

Also, you really should update Magit.

Comment: Running `customize-face` while point was at the face to be changed was the bit that I didn't know.  I've been able to modify the correct face for increased contrast.  The small font size on the mode-line went away when I restarted emacs after it hung when I tried to set the face height to 100 (tenths of a point).